# Why objects key still has unknow promise , though I have used await for mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm new to javascript. as I know using array.map over async function returns array of promises.
and I can use await Promise.all to reolve all promise and it returns me data.
**I want to understand how can I use asyn function inside array of object's key.
As I know using async function it never block as execution for unimportant line, ( here other execution is not dependent on url , so I'm trying to make it asynchronous)**

```
async function showPost() {
  const posts = [
    { title: 'a', url: ['q', 'o'] },
    { title: 'b', url: ['t', 'y'] },
  ];
  const formattedPost = await formatPosts(posts);
  console.log(formattedPost);
}

const formatPosts = async (posts) => {
  const formattedPosts = await Promise.all(   // NOTE: await promise.all on map
    posts.map(async (post) => {
      post.url = addUrl(post.url);    //NOTE: here if I don' add await here post.url is Promise<Unknown>
      return post;
    })
  );
  return formattedPosts;
};

const addUrl = async (d) => {
  const mm = await Promise.all(d.map((item) => item + '-dummyUrl'));
  return mm;
};

showPost();
```

**CODE 1 without await , but inside await Promise.all **
[image]

**CODE 2 with AWAIT on addURL call** I get output

[image]

Why is it not resolving though it is inside await promise.all

thanks for help in advance

Comment: Why do you have `addUrl` as async function? It does not do any async work it seems.

Comment: I'm just trying to depict a scenario, so just think add url is a common async function.
My main doubt is about why post.url is not resolving , ** if I am using await promise.all on parent level, since we can do await on Promise.all at outer side and we don't need to await inside it there are multiple await operation inside map function needed **, right?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Promise.all()`, you're resolving the promises returned by the `map()` function. When you don't add `await` to `addURL()`, you're replacing that value in the object with a promise object, which isn't resolved by `Promise.all()`.

Promises are still promises, even after they resolve.

On top of this, `Array.prototype.map()` isn't an async function, so `addURL()` doesn't need to be async, which makes adding `await` pointless.

Comment: Does that mean Promise.all will only resolve promises at upper level. Not nor nested level.
I noticed. assigning `addUrl` to variable  instead of object key will returns me data if I don't use await.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-kuyhd8?file=index.js

Comment: So on a broader perspective. suppose there are multiple `object keys` with some value to be calculated , i have to use `await` for each `async` function  assigned to object key , just like `post.url = await addUrl()`
and JS will wait till each line gets resolved and then it will move to next line to solve next problem ?
doesn't it makes a code synchronous, since I want to make it asynchronous, and post.calculateViewcount is not dependent on post.url , it can be a async call right ?

explanation will help me alot to learn JS. thanks in advance.

Comment: @bit555 It's still asynchronous, though the code in each `async` function is executed sequentially. Since `map` does multiple calls at once, they will still run concurrently, even when they do `post.prop1 = await promise1(); post.prop2 = await promise2()`. But yes, in there the `promise2()` would always only be called after the first promise completed. You'd have to write `[post.prop1, post.prop2] = await Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()])` to run those two concurrently.

Comment: Ohhh okay.. Now I understood it. I've to do `[post.prop1, post.prop2] = await Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()])` to make it  concurrently. 
means it works.
I think it work level wise.. If I'm using await Promise.all for array of post , it will work on posts. but If it do post.prop1 and prop2, the upper promise.all will not resolve it , So I've to use another Promise.all to make it concurrent at prop level.

thanks a lot @Bergi for explaining it. and @zmehall to u also

Answer (score 2):

> I know using array.map over async function returns array of promises, and I can use await Promise.all to resolve all promise and it returns me data.

This will just wait for the promises that are elements of the array that was passed to `Promise.all`, not "all promises" anywhere.

Notice that without the `await`, you don't need to make the `map` callback an `async` function, and you don't need to wait for the promises in the mapped array then; your current code is exactly equivalent to

```
const formatPosts = async (posts) => {
  const formattedPosts = posts.map((post) => {
    post.url = addUrl(post.url);
    return post;
  });
  return formattedPosts;
};
```

> Why objects key still has unknown promise

Because you assigned a promise object to the object property. Never did you instruct anything to wait for that promise. This is what would be fixed by doing

```
post.url = await addUrl(post.url);
```

Comment: thanks for explaining , As you and @zmehall pointed it out, I'm assigning Promise object to object key. But as I'm trying to learn more about JS can You explain my doubt which I have written as comment in zmehall's answer